# can not able to set Content type

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to save an image in azure blob storage. I set the content type by code, as follows but it is readying but not uploading. What should I do?

File upload code :

```cs
[HttpPost("ListFiles")]
public async Task<List<string>> InsertFile(List<IFormFile> asset)
{
    try
    {
        var urlList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var op in asset)
        {


            if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(_config.Value.StorageConnection, out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount))
            {
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_config.Value.Container);

                  var postedFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(op.FileName);
                var img = $@"{Guid.NewGuid()}" + postedFileExtension;
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(img);
                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(img);
                cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = op.ContentType;
                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(op.OpenReadStream());
                var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(img);

                urlList.Add(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            }

        }
        return urlList;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are updating the property on a second reference of the record, but not saving the changes back.  Either reuse the `blockBlob` and set it's `ContentType` to the value or save the `cloudBlockBlob`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using

```
var postedFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(op.FileName);
var img = $@"{Guid.NewGuid()}" + postedFileExtension;

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(img);
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(img);
cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = op.ContentType;

await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(op.OpenReadStream());
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(img);
```

You are setting the `ContentType` property of a variable but not committing this change to Azure.  Update the code to:

```
var postedFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(op.FileName);
var img = $@"{Guid.NewGuid()}" + postedFileExtension;

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(img);  
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = op.ContentType;

await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(op.OpenReadStream());
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(img);

Console.WriteLine(blob.Properties.ContentType); // Output the contentType
```

Answer (score 2):

To set content type while uploading the blob, just set the `ContentType` property before calling the upload method. The below is my test code, you could have a try.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String strorageconn = "storage string";
        CloudStorageAccount storageacc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(strorageconn);

        //Create Reference to Azure Blob
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageacc.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.jpg");

        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";

        using (var filestream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"D:\Picture\test.jpg"))
        {

            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(filestream);

        }
    }
```

And use Storage Explorer to read the properties, below is the result.

[image]